# Очередь в потоках Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, очередь

Изучая многопоточность, написал небольшой код который по идее должен по очереди запускать потоки, написал такой вот небольшой скрипт:

```
import queue
import threading

exit_flag = False


class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, thread_id, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.name = name
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        print("Starting {}".format(self.name))
        process_data(self.name, self.q)
        print("Exiting {}".format(self.name))


def process_data(working_thread, q):
    while not exit_flag:
        queue_lock.acquire()
        if not work_queue.empty():
            data = q.get()
            queue_lock.release()
            print("{} processing {}".format(working_thread, data))


thread_list = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
name_list = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

queue_lock = threading.Lock()
work_queue = queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
t_id = 1

for t_name in thread_list:
    thread = MyThread(t_id, t_name, work_queue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    t_id += 1

queue_lock.acquire()
for word in name_list:
    work_queue.put(word)
queue_lock.release()

while not work_queue.empty():
    pass

exit_flag = True

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print("Main thread end!")
```

Что самое интересное, во время работы в режиме дебагинга, всё нормально работает, а если просто так взять запустить, то ничего не происходит, только сообщение что поток запущен. Не подскажете где я допускаю ошибку?

Comment: своими словами, какое желаемое поведение вашего кода? Что вы пытаетесь достичь?

Comment: Ну вроде как я создал очередь потоков, которые должны работать, но потоки стартуют но действий никаких.. А если запустить в дебаг режиме (использую PyCharm) расставив брейкпоинты, в консоль все вроде как начинает выводить результаты потоков.. А если напрямую запустить то нет.

Comment: опишите не сломанную реализацию, а какое вы ожидаете поведение, которое снаружи видно (к примеру, на экран должно выводиться а, б, в, г, д в случайном порядке, а вместо этого ничего не выводится)

Comment: Единственное что кстати заметил, когда в дебаг режиме я дебажил, если убрать брейкпоинт например у начала функции `process_data()` то блок кода вообще игнорируется и вовсе не выполняется, а если поставить то всё ок. А то что я хочу, я хочу чтобы все три потока выполнили действия которые находятся в очереди

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import queue, threading, time

ResultDt = {}
ResultLock = threading.Lock()


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, q, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name=name, daemon=True)
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        print("Starting {}".format(self.name))
        while True:  # циклически получать задачи в потоке
            try:
                data = self.q.get(timeout=2)  # ожидать задачу в течение 2 сек
                print("{} processing {}".format(self.name, data))
            except queue.Empty:
                print('timeout выход', self.name)
                break
            else:  # из очереди получена задача
                try:
                    if data is None:
                        print('None выход', self.name)
                        break
                    else:
                        r = worker(data)  # выполнение задачи
                        ResultLock.acquire()  # заблокировать
                        ResultDt['run_{}'.format(data)] = r  # сохр. результат выполнения
                        ResultLock.release()  # освободить
                finally:  # task_done, при любом исходе
                    self.q.task_done()
        print("Exiting {}".format(self.name))


def worker(arg):
    """выполнение задач"""
    time.sleep(.5)
    return 'done_{}'.format(arg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_queue = queue.Queue()  # очередь задач
    threads = [MyThread(work_queue, t_name) for t_name in ("Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3")]  # потоки
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for word in ["One", None, "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]:  # задачи
        work_queue.put(word)
    work_queue.join()  # заблокировать до выполнения всех задач

    time.sleep(3)  # ожидать более timeout
    print(ResultDt)
    print("Main thread end!")
```

out

```
Starting Thread-1
Starting Thread-2
Starting Thread-3
Thread-1 processing One
Thread-2 processing None
None выход Thread-2
Thread-3 processing Two
Exiting Thread-2
Thread-1 processing Three
Thread-3 processing Four
Thread-1 processing Five
timeout выход Thread-3
Exiting Thread-3
timeout выход Thread-1
Exiting Thread-1
{'run_One': 'done_One', 'run_Two': 'done_Two', 'run_Three': 'done_Three', 'run_Four': 'done_Four', 'run_Five': 'done_Five'}
Main thread end!
```

Comment: Аа вот как надо было, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по принятому ответы вы хотите запустить `3` потока и обработать `5` слов в них:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def handle_word(word):
    time.sleep(5)
    return 'run_' + word, 'done_' + word

result = dict(ThreadPool(3).map(handle_word, ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]))
```

Пул потоков самостоятельно использует очередь внутри, предоставляя простой интерфейс.

Comment: Ого, про такое не знал)) Спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

Вместо блокировок `threading.Lock()` лучше воспользоваться возможностями `Queue`:

> Queue.task_done()
>
> Indicate that a formerly enqueued task is complete. Used by queue consumer threads. For each get() used to fetch a task, a subsequent
>   call to task_done() tells the queue that the processing on the task is
>   complete.
>
> If a join() is currently blocking, it will resume when all items have been processed (meaning that a task_done() call was received for
>   every item that had been put() into the queue).
>
> Raises a ValueError if called more times than there were items placed in the queue.

Документация: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html

Там же есть примеры

Comment: Хорошая подсказка, прочитал понял как работает, спасибо)